# Why the dragged element is shifted a few pixels after drop event?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a drag-and-drop demo, tested in google chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/eenrcu0c/9/

```
  var dragged, x, y;

  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      dragged = event.target;
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
          x = event.clientX;
          y = event.clientY;
          dragged.style.left = x + "px";
          dragged.style.top = y + "px";
      }

  }, false);
```

When I make "mouse up" (drop, dragend events) the draggable element moves. But it moves on some pixels to the right and lower than it should, not where cursor stopped. How should I make it move right to the place where it was dragged? I can deduct some pixels from x and y, but why does it happen? Does the problem lie in the different types of cursor (default and pointer)?